# Version conflict error When i try to update the sharepoint in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

```
            If dr(EDIData.STD_NUMBER).ToString() <> Nothing AndAlso dr(EDIData.STD_NUMBER).ToString() <> "" Then
                oListItem = oList.GetItemById(dr("STD"))
                oListItem.RefreshLoad()
                oListItem(EDIData.REMARKS) = String.Empty
                oListItem(EDIData.II_PROCESSED) = "TESTED"
```

--after this line the Error was accrued 
                    **oListItem.Update()
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery()**

Answer (score -1):

This may be the parameter you passed in addition to the problem, you can first check if the updated parameter has a problem.
Recommend you to look at this website:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539976(v%3doffice.14)
```

The code you might need:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
     class UpdateListItem
     {
        static void Main()
        {   
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
            ListItem oListItem = oList.Items.GetById(3);

            oListItem["Title"] = "My Updated Title.";

            oListItem.Update();

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
        }
     }
}
```